How to decode url like base64
my brothers. I have an encrypted link that is similar to base64. I have tried many times to restore it to its previous state, but to no avail. Is there anyone who can do that?
==gYKZWUPRUMTZTePR0cvUWbhJnZp9ie6VnYukGdsVXbh1WajtWd0tWd09yL6MHc0RHa0REL0Y&pOhMJQDN9h

I am trying to ask for help from programmers and I expect them to help me.

Why?  What do you think that is?  Where did you get it?  The leading "==" makes me think this is a MIME separator, in which case it has no meaning at all.

I don't expect base64 to start with the equal signs.  They commonly appear at the end to pad the base64 out appropriately.

@TimRoberts has a point.  Looking closely, it has an ampersand which is not going to appear in URL base64

FWIW, Son Le is correct.  If you reverse this and decode it, you get a file that does contain a URL.  But since this is not about programming, it doesn't belong here.

Reverse it first:
h9NDQJMhOp&Y0LER0aHR0cHM6Ly90dWt0dWtjaW1hbXVsdGkuYnV6ei9pZnJhbWUvc0RPeTZTMURPUWZKYg==
Then base64 decode
